# Playwright - how to check if element is in viewport?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, viewport, playwright

I have an array-like object of nodes (it is a carousel), their order is randomly generated with each page refresh, playwright finds all the elements to be visible, but some of them are outside the viewport (based on the error received). I need to make sure, that element is inside the viewport when attempting to click it, otherwise I get an error stating the element is outside.

How to determine if a randomly picked node element of an array-like object is actually within the viewport?

Answer (score 5):

Playwright unfortunately doesn't have a method like isInterSectingViewport in Puppeteer yet.([likethis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663356/check-visibility-in-viewport-puppeter))

So authors of Playwright help me in Slack community(you can find it on official site).

```
    const result = await page.$eval(selector, async element => {
      const visibleRatio: number = await new Promise(resolve => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
          resolve(entries[0].intersectionRatio);
          observer.disconnect();
        });
        observer.observe(element);
        // Firefox doesn't call IntersectionObserver callback unless
        // there are rafs.
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {});
      });
      return visibleRatio > 0;
    });
```

The case in which I used this method:
I want know that after I’m click some element - I have scrolling to another element. Unfortunately boundingBox method doesn’t help in my case.

also You can add this functionality to my BasePage class

```
/**
     * @returns {!Promise<boolean>}
     */
  isIntersectingViewport(selector: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.page.$eval(selector, async element => {
      const visibleRatio: number = await new Promise(resolve => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
          resolve(entries[0].intersectionRatio);
          observer.disconnect();
        });
        observer.observe(element);
        // Firefox doesn't call IntersectionObserver callback unless
        // there are rafs.
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {});
      });
      return visibleRatio > 0;
    });
  }
```

P.S.
In fact, all the code except for one line is taken from the realisation of method isInterSectingViewport in [GitHub Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/943477cc1eb4b129870142873b3554737d5ef252/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/JSHandle.js#L192)

Answer (score 4):

Playwright has added a [feature](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/8740) to enable checking this using "expect". The usage info is below:

```
 (method) LocatorAssertions.toBeInViewport(options?: {
    ratio?: number;
    timeout?: number;
}): Promise<void>
Ensures the Locator points to an element that intersects viewport, according to the intersection observer API.

Usage

const locator = page.getByRole('button');
// Make sure at least some part of element intersects viewport.
await expect(locator).toBeInViewport();
// Make sure element is fully outside of viewport.
await expect(locator).not.toBeInViewport();
// Make sure that at least half of the element intersects viewport.
await expect(locator).toBeInViewport({ ratio: 0.5 });
```

Comment: This is helpful in one of my use cases.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To check if element is in viewport using css selector:

```js
import { test, expect, devices } from '@playwright/test'

const url = 'https://example.com'
const selector = 'h1'

test.use({
    headless: false,
    browserName: 'webkit',
    ...devices['iPhone 13 Mini'],
})

test('visibility', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto(url)
    const box = await page.locator(selector).boundingBox() // it contains x, y, width, and height only
    let isVisible = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
        let isVisible = false
        let element = document.querySelector(selector)
        if (element) {
            let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
            if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.left >= 0) {
                const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
                const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0)
                if (rect.right <= vw && rect.bottom <= vh) {
                    isVisible = true
                }
            }
        }
        return isVisible
    }, selector)
    await expect(isVisible).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Everything inside `evaluate(callback)` is hard to debug**. Because the callback function is running inside the browser scope.

The other way is to utilize `locator.boundingBox()` and `page.viewportSize()` to implement your own `expect(locator).toBeInViewport()`, which sadly, only return `void` officially. Meaning we cannot receive a boolean, and perform subsequent actions based on that value. (e.g. do a scroll to emulate human behaviour)

Implementation is pretty simple:

```js
const box = await mylocator.boundingBox()
const view = page.viewportSize() // note: doesn't need await
const isMyLocatorInViewport = box.y + box.height - view.height < 0 && box.y > 0
```

Only work on Y axis but enough for a lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check if element is in viewport outside [assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-in-viewport) here is helpful function:

```js
    const isInViewport = async (element: Locator): Promise<boolean> => {
      const viewportSize = element.page().viewportSize();
      const boundingBox = await element.boundingBox();
    
      if ( !viewportSize || !boundingBox) {
        return false;
      }
    
      const isBoundingBoxVisible = boundingBox.x >= 0 && boundingBox.y >= 0;
      const isBoundingBoxInViewport =
        boundingBox.x + boundingBox.width <= viewportSize.width &&
        boundingBox.y + boundingBox.height <= viewportSize.height;
    
      return isBoundingBoxVisible && isBoundingBoxInViewport;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const firstId = "#someId"; 

// it happens that I am evaluating in a frame, rather than page 
const result = await frame.evaluate((firstId) => {

  // define a function that handles the issue
  // returns true if element is within viewport, false otherwise 
  function isInViewport(el) {

    // find element on page 
    const element = document.querySelector(el); 

    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <=
        (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <=
        (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }; 

  return isInViewport(firstId); 

}, firstId);



// back to node context 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to cardinalX [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848306/8371435).
You can create helper function using page.waitForFunction to wait until element to be in viewport

```
import { Page } from '@playwright/test';

export const waitToBeInViewport = async (
  page: Page,
  selector: string,
) => page.waitForFunction(async (selectorParam: string) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(selectorParam);
  const visibleRatio: number = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      resolve(entries[0].intersectionRatio);
      observer.disconnect();
    });
    observer.observe(element);
    requestAnimationFrame(() => { });
  });
  return visibleRatio > 0; // where 0 - element has just appeared, and 1 - element fully visible;
}, selector);
```

Comment: the return value im getting from this function is `{"_guid": "handle@73d2b54286357906ed761446c1a5c78a", "_type": "JSHandle"}`. probably im not using it correctly. any tips?